# Differences between PIL Image.open and cv2.imdecode

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two ways of loading images from bytes using PIL vs OpenCV.

```
def bytes_to_ndarray(bytes):
    bytes_io = bytearray(bytes)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(bytes_io))
    return np.array(img)
```

and

```
img = cv2.imdecode(bytes, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
```

The problem is that they seem to give different answers for image that was created using OpenCV. If `image` is an `ndarray`, then for

```
bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
```

these two ways will give different outputs, for example for `skimage.data.astronaut()`

PIL will give:

[image]

Whereas OpenCV will return correct image:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short: It's just the usual RGB vs. BGR ordering thing - but, the combination of how you use OpenCV's `imencode` and `imdecode` here with this specific image, makes everything totally complicated. ;-)

`skimage.data.astronaut()` returns a `ndarray` with RGB ordering, as RGB ordering is the standard in `skimage`. In contrast, OpenCV internally uses BGR ordering. So, when we would use `cv2.imread` on a saved PNG of this image, we would get a `ndarray` with BGR ordering. Also, OpenCV always assumes BGR ordered `ndarrays` for all its operations.

Now, you use `cv2.imencode` to generate the byte stream. As mentioned, OpenCV assumes the `ndarray` fed to that function has BGR ordering. That's important, because the generated byte stream will have RGB ordering (`cv2.imencode` mimics `cv2.imwrite`, and OpenCV correctly writes RGB images). So, the created byte stream has a false BGR ordering.

For the decoding, Pillow as well as OpenCV assume a RGB ordered byte stream. So, the `ndarray` created by the "Pillow way" actually has BGR ordering (which is NOT the Pillow standard) and the `ndarray` created by OpenCV's `imdecode` has RGB ordering (which is NOT the OpenCV standard).

Finally, Matplotlib's (or pyplot's) `imshow` assumes RGB ordered `ndarrays` for visualization. So, the following will happen:

- Showing the original `ndarray` from `skimage.data.astronaut()` should be correct (RGB ordered).
- Showing the Pillow loaded PNG should be correct (RGB ordered).
- Showing the OpenCV loaded PNG should be incorrect (BGR ordered).
- Showing the Pillow decoded byte stream should be incorrect (BGR ordered).
- Showing the OpenCV decoded byte stream should be correct (RGB ordered).

Let's see:

```py
import cv2
from io import BytesIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import skimage


def bytes_to_ndarray(bytes):
    bytes_io = bytearray(bytes)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(bytes_io))
    return np.array(img)


# skimage returns a ndarray with RGB ordering
img_sk = skimage.data.astronaut()

# Opening a saved PNG file of this image using Pillow returns a ndarray with RGB ordering
img_pil = Image.open('astronaut.png')

# Opening a saved PNG file of this image using OpenCV returns a ndarray with BGR ordering
img_cv = cv2.imread('astronaut.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# OpenCV uses BGR ordering, thus OpenCV's encoding treats img_sk[:, :, 0] as blue channel,
# although it's the actual red channel (the same for img_sk[:, :, 2]
# That means, the encoded byte stream now has BGR ordering!!
_, bytes = cv2.imencode('.png', img_sk)

# OpenCV uses BGR ordering, but OpenCV's decoding assumes a RGB ordered byte stream, so
# the blue and red channels are swapped again here, such that img_cv again is a ndarray with
# RGB ordering!!
img_byte_cv = cv2.imdecode(bytes, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)

# Pillow uses RGB ordering, and also assumes a RGB ordered byte stream, but the actual byte
# stream is BGR ordered, such that img_pil actually is a ndarray with BGR ordering
img_byte_pil = bytes_to_ndarray(bytes)

# Matplotlib pyplot imshow uses RGB ordering for visualization!!
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 12))
plt.subplot(3, 2, 1), plt.imshow(img_pil), plt.ylabel('PNG loaded with Pillow')
plt.subplot(3, 2, 2), plt.imshow(img_cv), plt.ylabel('PNG loaded with OpenCV')
plt.subplot(3, 2, 3), plt.imshow(img_sk), plt.ylabel('Loaded with skimage')
plt.subplot(3, 2, 5), plt.imshow(img_byte_pil), plt.ylabel('Decoded with Pillow')
plt.subplot(3, 2, 6), plt.imshow(img_byte_cv), plt.ylabel('Decoded with OpenCV')
plt.show()
```

Et voilà:

[image: Output]

Here's a PNG copy of the image to reproduce the code:

[image]

Bottom line: When using OpenCV's `imencode`, make sure, that the passed `ndarray` has BGR ordering!

Hope that helps!